# jQuery in widgets on WordPress pages does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, widget

I have some jQuery powered widgets on my WordPress site. They all work fine when I add them to the sidebar or footer.

However, I needed to add some widgets on my page, so I've used the [Widgets on Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-on-pages/) plugin to do so.

But, this seems to break the jQuery in the widgets, as all the effects are gone. You can see a demo of what I am talking about [here](http://dev.web2core.com/jugoistok/). The menu in the center of the page (below the banner) should have the same "hover" effect as the same menu in the footer.

I am pretty new to all this so I don't have a clue what to do. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: there is two error in your site that i found on firebug:  
unterminated string literal
spe_array[0] = '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually stopped using widgets and created a new plugin which loads the jQuery, so I've achieved what I wanted.